# Building a script to automatically save .xyz format files from geometry optimization with AMMP in VegaZZ

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-mechanics

I'm totally new to programming and computational chemistry.
I'm using Vega ZZ as a free software to compute geometry optimization via MM (AMMP) in order to optimize the geometry of the found minima with DFT (ORCA) afterwords.
My usual geometry optimization process is:

1. Sketching a molecule with the Ketcher editor in Vega ZZ
2. Sending the molecule to Vega ZZ and selecting the desired torsion angles
3. Starting a conformational research (with energy minimization) in AMMP based on the given torsion angles
4. Opening the .dcd file (what i believe is the trajectory file) in Vega with the Analysis function
5. Exporting the iteration/energy vector to Excel in order to sort-out the best iterations (in a 10Kcal/mol energy window, per say)
6. Going back to Vega ZZ and Saving each .xyz file INDIVIDUALLY from the best selected iterations
7. Starting a multijob DFT geometry optimization on ORCA (can do)

The most annoying steps as you can see are 4,5,6. Is there any way to automatize this process?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really thing that if you are going to optimize the energy, you don't need to search for conformers. Just draw the structure, do a single optimization step and save in the format you need to input to ORCA. ORCA will search for the minimum energy structure. IF ORCA fails, then use another structure as input (by another I mean a new conformer you can draw by your self).

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.